# Maven build failing when deploying, build succeeds when compiling

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment

I am using Gitlab_ci to trigger a maven script when code is pushed.

The script executes:

mvn compile

```
[...]
[INFO] project ............................................ SUCCESS [1.312s]
[INFO] project-api ........................................ SUCCESS [1.416s]
[INFO] project-api-impl ................................... SUCCESS [0.329s]
[INFO] project-webapp ..................................... SUCCESS [0.192s]
[INFO] project-webapp-exec ................................ SUCCESS [0.026s]
[INFO] project-webapp-it .................................. SUCCESS [2.052s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

mvn tomcat7:deploy

```
[INFO] project............................................ SUCCESS [1.840s]
[INFO] project-api ........................................ SUCCESS [2.524s]
[INFO] project-api-impl ................................... FAILURE [0.257s]
[INFO] project-webapp ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] project-webapp-exec ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project-webapp-it .................................. SKIPPED
```

And I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-api-impl: Could not resolve dependencies for project eu.project:project-api-impl:jar:0.6-DEVELOPMENT: Failure to find eu.project:project-api:jar:0.6-DEVELOPMENT in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Since the project builds successfuly (the WAR is created), I can't understand why when executing deploy, build fails.

[Also, I am not sure whether to mark this as homework. The assignment's goal is to create a tomcat web application and manually deploy to a server to test. Since maven / continuous integration wasn't a requisit, I believe this should not be marked as a homework question]

Comment: Please provide your `pom.xml`, especially the `tomcat plugin` configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because of timing constraints, I switched to using ant to build a war, and then used a bash script to deploy it. Since this suites my needs for this projects, I am abandoning Maven.
Also, in retrospect, my mistake was trying to create a Maven project out of an existing project. This was probably the cause of the error, since the build that succeeds produces only the "test" project as per the tomcat maven archetype.